# Unicode hexadecimal editor

Tags: linux, unicode, software-rec, editors

I am looking for a Linux editor or viewer with side by side panels displaying hexadecimal bytes and the visual representation and or code point of:

- at a minimum UTF-8
- at a maximum the entire Unicode standard encodings

Comment: When you say "hexadecimal and Unicode", do you mean like a traditional hex editor (showing bytes as hex) or something Unicode-specific (perhaps showing codepoints as hex)?

Comment: Thanks for your request to disambiguate the question.